# Unable to run project under Gulp

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm, gulp

I'm new to front-end development and I have some existing project which I unable to run.

Documentation says, to run the project I should execute:

```
$ gulp && gulp serve
```

However, I receive the following error:

```
/home/alex/some/project/node_modules/@types/gulp/index.d.ts(15,15): error TS2430: Interface 'Gulp' incorrectly extends interface 'Orchestrator'.
  Types of property 'task' are incompatible.
    Type 'AddMethod' is not assignable to type '{ (name: string): Task; (name: string, fn: TaskFunc): void; (name: string, dep: string[], fn: Tas...'.
      Type 'Orchestrator' is not assignable to type 'Task'.
        Property 'fn' is missing in type 'Orchestrator'.
```

What did I miss?

**Update:**

Here is my `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "Some | description",
  "author": "Author name",
  "homepage": "http://sample.org",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/angular": "^1.5.5-alpha",
    "@types/gulp": "^3.8.32",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.52",
    "autoprefixer": "^6.5.2",
    "browser-sync": "^2.18.5",
    "chai": "^3.5.0",
    "chai-as-promised": "^5.3.0",
    "del": "^2.2.2",
    "eslint": "^3.9.1",
    "eslint-config-angular": "^0.5.0",
    "eslint-plugin-angular": "^1.4.1",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-angular-filesort": "^1.1.1",
    "gulp-angular-templatecache": "^2.0.0",
    "gulp-autoprefixer": "^3.1.1",
    "gulp-clean": "^0.3.2",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.6.1",
    "gulp-cssmin": "^0.1.7",
    "gulp-eslint": "^3.0.1",
    "gulp-htmlmin": "^3.0.0",
    "gulp-if": "^2.0.2",
    "gulp-imagemin": "^3.1.1",
    "gulp-inject": "^4.1.0",
    "gulp-jade": "^1.1.0",
    "gulp-jscs": "^4.0.0",
    "gulp-jsdoc3": "^1.0.1",
    "gulp-load-plugins": "^1.4.0",
    "gulp-print": "^2.0.1",
    "gulp-replace": "^0.5.4",
    "gulp-rev": "^7.1.2",
    "gulp-sass": "^3.0.0",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "^2.4.1",
    "gulp-stylelint": "^3.9.0",
    "gulp-tslint": "^7.0.1",
    "gulp-typescript": "^3.1.3",
    "gulp-uglify": "^2.0.0",
    "gulp-util": "^3.0.8",
    "husky": "^0.13.1",
    "jasmine": "^2.5.2",
    "jshint": "^2.9.4",
    "karma": "^1.3.0",
    "karma-angular": "^0.0.6",
    "karma-chai": "^0.1.0",
    "karma-chai-as-promised": "^0.1.2",
    "karma-mocha": "^1.3.0",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-requirejs": "^1.1.0",
    "merge-stream": "^1.0.1",
    "mocha": "^3.1.2",
    "path-exists": "^3.0.0",
    "phantomjs-prebuilt": "^2.1.13",
    "requirejs": "^2.2.0",
    "run-sequence": "^1.2.2",
    "rxjs": "^5.0.1",
    "serve-static": "^1.11.1",
    "simple-git": "^1.65.0",
    "stream-series": "^0.1.1",
    "tslint": "^4.3.1",
    "typescript": "^2.1.4",
    "wiredep": "^4.0.0",
    "yargs": "^6.5.0"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=0.10.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "bower install",
    "start": "npm install",
    "js-doc": "rm -rf ./docs && gulp js-doc && open docs/gen/global.html",
    "precommit": "node enforceLinter.js"
  }
}
```

Here is a `serve` task in my `gulpfile.js`

```
gulp.task("serve", ["copymapdata", "imagemin", "copyfonts", "copyskins", "copyother", "inject"], () => {
    browserSync.init({
        open: true,
        port: 8000,
        reloadDelay: 3000,
        server: {
            baseDir: ".tmp",
            routes: {
                "/bower_components": "./app/bower_components"
            },
            cors: true,
            middleware: function(req, res, next) {
                res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
                res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*");
                next();
            }
        }
    });
    gulp.watch(config.allcss, ["styles"]);
    gulp.watch(config.alljs, ["js-watch"]);
    gulp.watch(config.alljade, ["jade-watch"]);
    gulp.watch(config.allts, ["ts-watch"]);
});
```

Comment: Looks like a messed up `Orchestrator` typing. Can you add your `package.json` and perhaps parts of the `gulpfile`

Comment: @Dinistro, I've updated my question. Is it enough?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update your gulp to latest version "@types/gulp": "^4.0.3"

Comment: Thank you, but removing caret(^) symbol doesn't have an effect.

Comment: Update your gulp to latest version   "@types/gulp": "^4.0.3"

Comment: This time, you are absolutely right! Please, update your answer. Thanks!