# Error while building @angular/material2

Tags: gulp, angular-material2

I just took the latest version of Angular material 2 . 
I try to build and it gives gulp build error. I am sure something is wrong , can anyone else try if its building fine.

```
TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript
node_modules/@types/run-sequence/node_modules/@types/gulp/index.d.ts (15,15): Interface 'Gulp' incorrectly extends interface 'Orchestrator'.
  Types of property 'task' are incompatible.
    Type 'AddMethod' is not assignable to type '{ (name: string): Task; (name: string, fn: TaskFunc): void; (name: string, dep: string[], fn: Tas...'.
      Type 'Orchestrator' is not assignable to type 'Task'.
        Property 'fn' is missing in type 'Orchestrator'. (2430)
tools/gulp/tasks/ci.ts (4,17): Argument of type 'string[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'TaskFunction'.
  Type 'string[]' provides no match for the signature '(done: (error?: any) => void): any'. (2345)
```

Node version : v6.9.1 
gulp version: 3.9.1

Tried this solution : [Unable to run project under Gulp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44125605/unable-to-run-project-under-gulp) 
did not work .

Its great if someone can help me fix this, at least even if I know for sure that its working for others , I will try to fix it.

Comment: Did you try updating gulp? (run `npm update`)

Comment: I already have latest gulp. I updated `@type/gulp` . 
if I update, `@type/run-sequence` gives error. To fix that I updated that too . 
Now it says gulp task takes object, cannot pass `String[]` . I could not go further